# How to link Android NDK shared library?

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, linker

I can build an produce all platform shared library. I have a makefile name Android.mk as:

```
 LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
 include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 LOCAL_SRC_FILES := com_masum_test_JniTest.c
 LOCAL_MODULE := com_masum_test_JniTest
 include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Another file named Application.mk as:

```
APP_ABI := all
```

When I enter command ndk-build it creates all shared library.

But when I call native function I get exception as :-

09-11 15:57:02.018  22949-22949/com.masum.test E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.masum.test, PID: 22949
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity

Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.masum.test-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.masum.test-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libcom_masum_test_JniTest.so"

I don't even see the lib folder in my work space. Check the pic:-
[image]

File explorer:-

[image]

Clearly my application cannot link with the shared library. So how to link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to link. If I make a directory named jniLibs inside app/src/main and then copy all the share library in side. It is able to link and load library. Note that directory name "jniLibs" is case sensitive.

You must call this in source code:-

```
static{
    System.loadLibrary("libray_name"); // without prefix 'lib' and suffix '.so' i.e. "libLibName.so" should be only LibName. 
}
```